# Dynamic pointer manipulation C-Programming

Tags: c, function, pointers, dynamic, free

I would like to gain a better grasp on dynamic pointers.

```
int main(){ 

  // allocate pointer
  randomStructure *pt = (randomStructure *)malloc(sizeof(randomStructure));

  // arbitrary code that manipulates data that *pt points to. 

  // function call
  function(pt);

  return 0;
}


void function(randomStructure *pt){

   randomStructure *tempPt = (randomStructure *)malloc(sizeof(randomStructure));

   // arbitrary code that manipulates data that *tempPt points to. 

   pt = tempPt;

   //free(tempPt); Question2

   /* Question 4
   while(index){
     randomStructure *tempPt = (randomStructure *)malloc(sizeof(randomStructure));

   }
   */

}
```

Questions:

1. When I pass the `*pt` to a function, does it automatically update the `*pt` in main or do I need to return `*pt` from the function to do that?
2. If I free the `*tempPt` in the function does it also free `*pt`?
3. If I malloc a `*tempPt` inside a function, will the data that it points to be automatically freed after the function ends?
4. This question may be answered indirectly from the previous questions, but how would I create a `*tempPt` and deallocate it in a loop without deallocating `*pt` so that the process can be repeated?

EDIT Question 4: Perhaps a more specific example of what I'm trying to do will clarify the question. I am running a basic Heuristic algorithm. After I pass the pointer to a function, I manipulate the data, and I then run the algorithm and point to it with *tempPt. If the *tempPt's data is more optimized than *pt's, I want to update *pt with *tempPt's data.

Comment: what is a "Dynamic pointer" ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use valedictions or signatures. SO isn't a discussion list, it's more of an online reference book of programming problems. Conciseness and clarity is very important and conversely, fluff is not desired. Please read "[ask]" for more information.

Comment: Gotcha my bad. It's my first post. All advice is greatly appreciated! I'm not entirely sure how I would call a pointer that points to dynamically allocated memory, so I just termed it "Dynamic Pointer". Perhaps my example code would shed more light on it?

Comment: There are many existing questions on SO which revolve around the by-value parameter passing semantics of C function calls, and how that interacts with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you change the memory address that `pt` points to(like you have in the included function), it will not update the memory address  pointed to by the pointer in the main function. However, if you change the data at that memory address `pt` in the main function will also point to that changed data.
2. Yes, as they both point to the same underlying data.
3. No, C does not have automatic garbage collection and as such any memory declared on the heap must be explicitly freed.
4. I'm somewhat unsure of what you are asking. If you free `tempPt`, `pt` is going to be a dangling pointer in the code you have shown, as they both point to the same underlying data. Thus, if `temptPt == pt`, it is impossible to free the data pointed at by `tempPt` without also freeing the data pointed at by `pt` as they point to the same thing.

Comment: Appreciate it! I updated Question 4, to shed a little more light on what I am attempting to do.

Comment: If `tempPt` and `pt` don't point to the same data, you can free the data pointed to by `pt` and then return `tempPtr` from the function. So, your function call would be `pt = function(pt);`

Comment: Great, I was just thinking the same thing! I really appreciate it. Cheers